# PHP script not entirely executing. just in new host server Unlike the old host

Tags: php, xml, server, hosting

I'm having problem with a php script that is stock data to xml file , and it's just simply not being executed. I get the same code i wrote it in the the output page (in the browser). I am quite sure this is a PHP setting problem because before I have changed the host server it was working fine. That is the codes :

```
 <?php

 $tag = $price ='ds';

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 $tag = test_input($_POST["comdtyprice"]);
 $price = test_input($_POST["comdtyprice"]);

 }
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("b.xml");

 $child = $xml->prices[0]->addChild($tag);

 $child->addAttribute("text",$price);
 $xml->asXML("b.xml");

 function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
 }
 ?>
```

and the output:
[image: picture from the browser]
the browser act with the codes as a string

Comment: My guess would be that the server does not have php installed. What OS and webserver are you running?

Comment: Or on the second server, xml extension isn't installed. On the second server, what returns a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` ?

Comment: thanks for your help br. Operating System:Linux/Apache version:2.2.15/ PHP version:5.4.25

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the XML is somehow being interpreted as PHP. Perhaps an XML `?>` is encountered, which drops the interpreter out of PHP parsing. This might explain why only part of the code is being echoed out.

Comment: thanks br .please how to fix it

Comment: What do you get from `echo "<pre>" . print_r($xml, true) . "</pre>"` after loading the file?

Comment: Thanks for your attention Mark ?it is the same result .but this time the output was start from :" . print_r($xml, true) . "</pre>"..........................

Comment: it looks like ,the interpreter close the secript from the first ">" it find .and all the rest after this ">" will output to the secreen as a string .I am depressed   brother

Comment: Do you have access to the PHP error_log for your server? Perhaps some clues might show up there. Right now, I'm simply trying to suggest some troubleshooting. Is the `b.xml` file well formed?

Comment: yes b.xml looking good